# Problem in loading the package fPortfolio in R

Tags: r, installation, package

Getting the following error message while loading the package fPortfolio. Please help.

```
> library(fPortfolio)

Loading required package: fAssets

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fAssets’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):

there is no package called ‘mnormt’

Error: package ‘fAssets’ could not be loaded

In addition: Warning messages:

1: package ‘fPortfolio’ was built under R version 3.6.3

2: package ‘fAssets’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

Comment: Install the mnormt package. Also, what version of R are you using?

Comment: I tried installing mnormt package but its not showing as available.

Comment: The version details are as follows:R version 3.6.1

Comment: Can you update R to v4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You need install mnormt, must have R 4.0.0.

An alternative is :

```
install.packages("IntroCompFinR")
install.packages("IntroCompFinR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```